# Sending files as an attachment Django

Tags: python, django, django-1.11

I have created an XLS file and want to send it as an attachment to an email. The following code is working fine and I receive an email with the XLS file (status code is 200 OK).

```
# This is working code
import xlwt
import StringIO
import zipfile

from django.core.mail import EmailMessage


work_book = xlwt.Workbook()

# Here some boring stuff with excel
...

report_name = "do_something_%(username)s_%(current_date)s.xls"

f = StringIO.StringIO()
work_book.save(f)

message = EmailMessage(
    subject=u"Sample Title",
    body=u"Sample body",
    to=["test@company.com"])

message.attach(report_name, f.getvalue())
message.send()
```

But if I try to send compressed XLS file (using zipfile), i don't receive anything (However status code is "200 OK").
I replaced the last 2 lines of code with the following:

```
report_name_zip = 'do_something_%(username)s_%(current_date)s.zip'

with zipfile.ZipFile(f, mode='w', compression=zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED) as zf:
    zf.writestr(zinfo_or_arcname=report_name, bytes=f.getvalue())

message.attach(report_name_zip, f.getvalue())
message.send()
```

Comment: You both read and write to the same `StringIO`?

Comment: Should `zf.writestr(zinfo_or_arcname=report_name, bytes=f.getvalue())` not have `zinfo_or_arcname=report_name_zip`?

Comment: @DanielHolmes: the `report_name` is the name of the file if I understand it correctly, the `report_name_zip` is the name of the zipfile.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Ah okay, I see now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You read and write both to `stringIO`. You should use two separate `StringIO`s:

```
report_name_zip = 'do_something_%(username)s_%(current_date)s.zip'

report_name = "do_something_%(username)s_%(current_date)s.xls"

f1 = StringIO.StringIO()
work_book.save(f1)

f2 = StringIO.StringIO()
with zipfile.ZipFile(f2, mode='w', compression=zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED) as zf:
    zf.writestr(zinfo_or_arcname=report_name, data=f1.getvalue())

message.attach(report_name_zip, f2.getvalue())
message.send()
```